# How configure the Azure notification hub for testing without paying

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

For my `NET8` `MAUI` application, I tried to implement `Azure Notification Hub`. I did it. After a month, I received a bill from Microsoft.

[image]

The `Notification hub namespace` is using the free version.

[image]

When I create a new `notification hub`, I don't have any option apart from the name. When I create one, the option **Availability zone** is enabled and I can't find a way to disable it.

[image]

I disabled the **Recovery region** from the `Notification hub` but I'm still paying.

[image]

How can I disable the **Availability zones**?